# Is there a Windows 8 shortcut to display the current time?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8-preview

Using Windows 8 with keyboard and mouse, when you are on the desktop and you move the mouse to the lower left corner, the time is displayed in a popup window.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do the same without using the mouse?

Update: thanks to Kate for the answer.  A recent post on the [Windows Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-53-48-metablogapi/4667.Keyboard_2D00_shortcuts_2D00_for_2D00_Windows_2D00_8_5F00_5756566F.png) now has a [comprehensive list of system keyboard shortcuts](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/archive/2012/03/08/getting-around-in-windows-8.aspx) for the Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

Comment: It may not exist in the developer preview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows-C (for charms) brings up the same things as swiping from the side, including the clock. It's not just the clock, but it does include the clock.

edit - I got to my slate and confirmed this. From both the classic desktop and the start screen, win C gets you charms and clock.

Answer (score -1):

It's not very helpful, but I have been through the Winkey +alphabet (Checking other people's posts) and did not see one that brought up the clock in Win 7 or Win 8.